# C programming TEXT FILE not reading whole line

Tags: c, text

Here is the input from TEXT FILE :

```
19 BISON-BURGER 10 15.000000
10 BRAISED-COD 5 17.000000
23 MOJITO 8 11.000000
3 IRISH-COFEE 6 2.300000
7 LAMB-SHOULDER 8 23.000000
```

The output came out from compiler after input being key in was :

```
10 BRAISED-COD 5 17.000000
3 IRISH-COFEE 6 2.300000
7 LAMB-SHOULDER 8 23.000000
```

Why the compiler skipping some of the lines ? Is there any changes I need to make?

Please help. Thank you so much.

Here is the full code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct product
{
    int quantity, reorder, i, id;
    char name[20];
    float price;
};

    int main()
    {
    FILE * fp;

    int i=0;
    struct product a;
    system("cls");

    char checker;

        do
        {
        fp = fopen("addproduct.txt","a+t");
        system("cls");

        printf("Enter product ID : ");
        scanf(" %d", &a.id);

        printf("Enter product name : ");
        scanf(" %s", a.name);

        printf("Enter product quantity : ");
        scanf(" %d", &a.quantity);

        printf("Enter product price : ");
        scanf(" %f", &a.price);


        fprintf(fp, "%d %s %d %f\n\n", a.id, a.name, a.quantity, a.price);
        printf("Record saved!\n\n");

        fclose(fp);

        printf("Do you want to enter new product? Y / N : ");

        scanf(" %c", &checker);
        checker = toupper(checker);

        i++;

        system("cls");
        }

        while(checker=='Y');



        if(checker == 'N')
        {
        fp = fopen("addproduct.txt","r");

        while(fscanf(fp, "%d %s %d %f", &a.id, a.name, &a.quantity, &a.price)==4)
            {
        fscanf(fp, "%d %s %d %f", &a.id, a.name, &a.quantity, &a.price);
        printf("%d %s %d %f\n\n", a.id, a.name, a.quantity, a.price);
            }

        fclose(fp);

        }


        return(0);
}
```

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger. Then you can step through the code line by line to see what it's really doing, while monitoring variables and see how they change.

Comment: Because you read the line twice: once in the `while` condition, and again in the body of `while`. That does not read the same line, it reads another one.

Comment: Why do you keep opening and closing the output file each time through the input loop? Why not just open it once before the loop, and then close it after the loop ends?

Comment: @FredK okay cool. already change it. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading two lines from the file on each iteration of the output loop.  Get rid of the extra `scanf`:

```
    while(fscanf(fp, "%d %s %d %f", &a.id, a.name, &a.quantity, &a.price)==4)
    {
        printf("%d %s %d %f\n\n", a.id, a.name, a.quantity, a.price);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `fscanf()` twice each time through the `while` loop. First in the `while` condition, then in the body of the loop. You're only printing the variables read by the second one, so the lines read by the first `fscanf()` are being ignored. Get rid of the second `fscanf()`.

```
while(fscanf(fp, "%d %s %d %f", &a.id, a.name, &a.quantity, &a.price)==4)
{
    printf("%d %s %d %f\n\n", a.id, a.name, a.quantity, a.price);
}
```